# What language does the $("css stuff ") statement belong to?

Tags: jquery, css

I am novice who is starting to learn RoR and a bunch of related frameworks and have been writing and reviewing a lot of code that has the following statements to select for CSS elements in the DOM

```
$(".a .b .c")
```

Is this jQuery? I am not sure as it is often embedded inside ruby on rails code.

Comment: jQuery or some other javascript framework (probably jquery).

Comment: looks like jquery except for that &

Comment: **Not jquery**.. As the class names precede by `.` `$('.A .B > .D')`

Comment: @Sushanth-- I think the A B stuff is more of a representation of elements but maybe the OP means literally A B

Comment: sorry i meant to write generic CSS elements a la http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/. the &c. i just wrote to mean etc. :).

Comment: [CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/) selectors implemented in [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) using [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/).

Comment: In modern browsers, you can make a similar selection using native methods. `document.querySelectorAll(".a .b > .c")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a jQuery selector, It is used to target elements in a page :)

It is a valid thing to write because it is written in the syntax of the jQuery javascript framework.

Here is a specific example from the jQuery documentation concerning class selectors: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Selectors are used to target elements in the DOM so that you may make changes to it.

**Examples**

```
// Remove all elements with the "myclass" class.
$(".myclass").remove();

// Remove all paragraphs that are a direct descendant of an element with the "myid" id.
$("#myid > p").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is javascript with most likely the jQuery framework.

The `$("css stuff")` allows you to select an element based on its css selectors.

Comment: Could be zepto or some other frameworks too.

Answer (score 1):

that is javascript, specifically `$` is a name of a function, used as a shortcut for the `jQuery` object, usually you see it within something like

```
(function($){
    console.log($);
})(jQuery);
```

what it does is declaring an anonymous function that accepts a parameter called `$` and then calls immediately that function with the actual parameter the `jQuery` object.

You may have noticed that the `$` object could not not refer to jQuery object, that is because you can "pass to that function" a different object, for example using another framework like mootools, or you name it.

I would precise there that I have used 'funcion' and 'object' to refer to jQuery and $ interchangeably, to know why you should learn javascript!

Answer (score 0):

It jQuery selector,which is used to select elements that are present in the DOM of the loaded page.

For further reference you could refer the jQuery documentation for selectors: [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)